# Assigning different values to an element in a string

Tags: string, r

I'm using R.
Let's say I have a vector of cities and I want to use those city names individually
in a string.

```
city = c("Dallas", "Houston", "El Paso", "Waco")

phrase = c("Hey {city}, what's the meaning of life?")
```

So I want to end up with four seperate phrases.

```
"Hey Dallas, what's the meaning of life?"
"Hey Houston, what's the meaning of life?"
...
```

Is there a function similar to format() in Python which will allow 
me to perform this task in a simple/efficient manner?

Would like to avoid something like below.

```
for( i in city){
    phrase = c("Hey ", i, "what's the meaning of life?")
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

How about `sprintf`?

```
> city = c("Dallas", "Houston", "El Paso", "Waco")
> phrase = c("Hey %s, what's the meaning of life?")
> sprintf(phrase, city)
[1] "Hey Dallas, what's the meaning of life?"  "Hey Houston, what's the meaning of life?"
[3] "Hey El Paso, what's the meaning of life?" "Hey Waco, what's the meaning of life?"
```

Comment: There's no printf, but you can roll your own with `printf <- function(format_string, ...) {cat(sprintf(format_string, ...))}`

Answer (score 7):

Depending on how complicated it needs to be, a simple paste could do the job:

```
paste("Hey ", city, ", what's the meaning of life", sep="")
```

does what you want.

@Zach's answer, sprintf has a lot of advantages though, like proper formatting of doubles etc.